# Returning more than one value in a function of near protocol contract

Tags: rust, nearprotocol, rust-wasm

I am trying to return two variables in near protocol smart contract

```
   pub fn get_product(&self, product_id: u128) -> (String, bool) {
        let product = self.product_map.get(&product_id).unwrap();
        (product.product_details_hash, product.product_expired)
    }
```

Javascript code:

```
let hash = await nearcontract.contract.get_product({ product_id: 1 })
```

It gives an error of

```
Cannot deserialize value with Borsh
```

Also, is it possible to return struct directly?
e.g.

```
 pub fn get_product(&self, product_id: u128) -> Product {
        let product = self.product_map.get(&product_id).unwrap();
        product
    }
```

It too gives error:

```
the trait `avrit::create_profile::_IMPL_SERIALIZE_FOR_Input::_serde::Serialize` is not implemented for `avrit::avritstructs::Product
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first path should work fine. The `Cannot deserialize value with Borsh` might be coming from the `product_map` being corrupted due to prefix conflicts or the contract state was reused due to redeploy.

The 2nd path requires `serde::Serialize` to be implemented on the `Product`. You can do this using derive when defining `Product` struct.

```rust
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct Product {
...
```